# Can't change cursor to jpg file

Tags: html, css

I have a jpg file stored in the same folder as my styles.css, and I'm trying to change the cursor on a webpage to this jpg file. However, for some reason, it just isn't changing.

Right now this is being done through:

```
body {
    cursor: url(cursor.jpg), auto;
}
```

However, when I try something else, like `cursor: move;` it works fine, I just can't get the custom cursor to change. Could it be because the image is too big for a cursor (it is currently 416x416 pixels)? I know isn't a file path error since I'm not getting any errors in the console and if I go to inspect HTML and hover over the image link in the CSS, it displays the image, so I know that the webpage is getting it. But why is my cursor not changing?

Comment: In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: Ah okay, so there would be something similar in Chrome (the browser I'm using) right

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, cursors cannot be larger than 128x128:

```css
section {
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
    cursor: url(https://via.placeholder.com/128x128), auto;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
    cursor: url(https://via.placeholder.com/129x129), auto;
}
```

```html
<section>Small cursor</section>
<section>Large cursor</section>
```

This applies to all my Windows desktop browsers (Chrome, Edge and Firefox).

All you could do is to emulate it with JavaScript.